# ArcGIS 10.3 Address Locator - Partial Searches Not Working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding, arcgis-10.3, address

I'm using an address locator service based off an address point feature class in ArcGIS 10.3.  My ultimate goal is to write an app which will parse a list of addresses in a database and determine the X/Y coordinates for them.

So far the service is working correctly, however it is not returning results when search terms are only partially entered.

For example:

1. "2150 Main St" returns data
2. "2150 Main" returns data
3. "2150 Ma" does not return data

I have tried searching using wildcards, but that has not made a difference.  I know that ArcGIS 10.3 has the option of doing a Suggest operation, but that will not work since all of these searches will be happening behind the scenes.

Does anyone know how I can enable the locator to work with partial search terms?

Comment: Did you find the solution to that? I am facing the exact same problem!